# Print interface map with types

Tags: dictionary, go, interface, printf

I have a function that takes in some bytes, and parses them into a map. I would
like to print out this map, but with the types included if possible. I tried
this:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   m := map[string]interface{}{
      "one": uint16(1), "two": map[string]interface{}{
         "three": uint32(3), "four": uint64(4),
      },
   }
   /*
   map[string]interface {}{
      "one":0x1, "two":map[string]interface {}{"four":0x4, "three":0x3}
   }
   */
   fmt.Printf("%#v\n", m)
}
```

but it doesnt print out the number types. I can do this:

```
// uint16
fmt.Printf("%T\n", m["one"])
```

but the map can be pretty big, so I would like to avoid having to manually print
every value. Is it possible to do what I am wanting?

Answer (score 3):

Use for loops and recursion to print map values types:

```
func printTypes(m map[string]interface{}, indent string) {
    for k, v := range m {
        fmt.Printf("%s%s: %T\n", indent, k, v)

        // Recurse if value is a nested map
        if m, ok := v.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
            printTypes(m, indent+"  ")
        }

    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
printTypes(m, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to control the creation of the map, you can use custom types
instead:

```
package object
import "fmt"

type (
   Uint16 uint16
   Uint32 uint32
   Uint64 uint64
)

func (u Uint16) GoString() string {
   return fmt.Sprintf("uint16(%v)", uint16(u))
}

func (u Uint32) GoString() string {
   return fmt.Sprintf("uint32(%v)", uint32(u))
}

func (u Uint64) GoString() string {
   return fmt.Sprintf("uint64(%v)", uint64(u))
}
```

Or, you can override the whole map:

```
package object
import "fmt"

type object map[string]interface{}

func (o object) GoString() string {
   str := "map[string]interface{}{"
   first := true
   for key, val := range o {
      if first {
         first = false
      } else {
         str += ","
      }
      str += fmt.Sprintf("%q:", key)
      switch typ := val.(type) {
      case uint16:
         str += fmt.Sprintf("uint16(%v)", typ)
      case uint32:
         str += fmt.Sprintf("uint32(%v)", typ)
      case uint64:
         str += fmt.Sprintf("uint64(%v)", typ)
      default:
         str += fmt.Sprintf("%#v", val)
      }
   }
   return str + "}"
}
```

https://godocs.io/fmt#GoStringer